# How to send access token to route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token

I have route:

```
Route::post('user/create', 'Api\UserController@create');
```

I wish send to route header with access token //bearer token.
how can I?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `post` method and pass the header, you don't need to change it in `route`.

In the controller, you can get the header as below.

```
$input = $request->all();
$headers = $request->headers->all();
```

If you want to get access token then.

```
if(isset($headers["token"]) && count($headers["token"]) > 0) {
    $bearer_token = $headers["token"][0];
}
```

Comment: what I write in api.php?